# SQL синтаксис в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите найти ошибку. Возвращает ошибку

```
ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
********** Ошибка **********
```

ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
SQL-состояние: XX000

---

```
select   to_date(b.bdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY') between c.open_date and '08.03.2016', 
to_char (c.open_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), to_char ('08.03.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
from    (select '08.03.2016' bdate) b,
hsp_record h
inner join mc_step s on h.id = s.id
inner join mc_case c on c.id = s.case_id
left join mc_step sc on sc.id = c.closing_step_id
where h.id = 18731871
and ((to_date(b.bdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY') between c.open_date and '08.03.2016') is false)
and '08.03.2016' is not null
limit 1
```

Comment: А вот это: `to_char ('08.03.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY')` зачем ? вы же и так готовую строку даете. зачем еще раз в строку превращать да еще и по маске

Comment: Там переменная :Date и я ее временно заменил на дату. Все верно, тут ошибка

Comment: Ну поубирайте части запроса что бы понять в каком месте, но судя по тексту ошибки он не может понять тип аргумента, значит датой его не считает